# Proof of $\sum a_n$ converges, $a_n \geq 0 \implies \sum a_n^2$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, solution-verification

I am familiar with the proof using the comparison test, but I was wondering if it is possible to prove this result in the following way:

We know that the sequence $a_n$ converges, therefore $\exists M$ such that $M \geq a_n, \forall n$. So,
$$|a_n^2 + a_{n+1}^2 + \ldots + a_{n+p}^2| \leq M |a_n + a_{n+1} + \ldots + a_{n+p}|$$
Now, given that $\sum a_n$ is convergent, by Cauchy's criterion, $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists n_0$ such that $\forall n > n_0, p \in \mathbb{N}$ we have
$$|a_n + a_{n+1} + \ldots + a_{n+p}| < \frac{\epsilon}{M}$$
Thus,
$$|a_n^2 + a_{n+1}^2 + \ldots + a_{n+p}^2| < M \frac{\epsilon}{M} = \epsilon  $$

Comment: $|a_n| <1$ for $n$ sufficiently large and $|a_n^{2}|  \leq |a_n|$ for such $n$.

Comment: $a_n\to0\implies 0\leq a_n<\frac12$ when $n$ is large enough!

Comment: It's safer to use $\leq$ instead of $<$ (at one point in your argument, a strict inequality doesn't have to hold).

Comment: Thanks Michał! You're right. I fixed the first inequality now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your argument is correct. If you look up the proof of the comparison test, you should see something similar to this.

As pointed out in comments, you're free to choose $M>0$ arbitrarily. Taking $M := 1$ would simplify the argument slightly.

Answer (score 2):

We can see that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n}^{2}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n=0$.

Based on this,we can know that the original proposition holds.